# Regex to check capitalization of keyword

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a keyword `ProcessTest` and I want to match all occurrences that are not capitalized that way, in order to replace them with correctly spelled keyword.

```
PROCESSTEST >> ProcessTest
Processtest >> ProcessTest
proceSstest >> ProcessTest
```

Etc.

So I first need a case-insensitive match for the keyword, an next a case sensitive check for the correctly spelled keyword.

Any suggestions how to do this with regex?

Comment: It's a false good idea, don't make the distinction. Build a pattern to match the keyword capitalized or not and convert it.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: no need to use regex, just do a non-case-sensitive search and replace. Any text editors can do that

Comment: @casimir-et-hippolyte clear, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @casimir-et-hippolyte, simply match the word globally with case insentitive option (`gi`) then replace it.

Code is very simple and efficient in every language. Why add complexity when it is not necessary ? ;)

**Here is a sample**

```js
var text = "This is ProCeSSTesT or processTest or PROCESSTEST. This is FooBAR or martyMCfly or foobAr"
var words = ["ProcessTest", "FooBar", "MartyMcFly"]

words.forEach(function(word) {
  var re = new RegExp(word, "gi")
  text = text.replace(re, word)
})

console.log(text)
```

**Some improvements**

When searching for `ProcessTest` You certainly don't want to match words like `preProcessTest` or `processTester`, so let's update our regex like this : `\bprocesstest\b`

I didn't use lookaheads because not every language support them.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPxT5v/1)

```js
var text = "This is ProCeSSTesT or processTester or PROCESSTEST. This is FooBAR or martyMCfly or foobAr or preProcessTest and DummyFooBar"
var words = ["ProcessTest"]

words.forEach(function(word) {
  var re = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "gi")
  text = text.replace(re, word)
})

console.log(text)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPxT5v/2)

Comment: Be careful with `(^|\s)(processtest)(\s|$)` since it can't match two consecutive keywords (because of the overlapping space): `"processtest processtest"`. It's more simple to use word-boundaries (if possible): `\bprocesstest\b` or if the keyword has non-word characters and if the delimiter is a space to use a lookahead: `(^|\s)processtest(?!\S)`

Comment: You're right, this one also works, `\W` is better than `\s` : `(^|\W)?(ProcessTest)(\W|$)?`

Comment: If you make `(^|\W)` optional you will match something like: `"processtestprocesstest"`. Using word-boundaries is a better solution since they're *zero-width assertions*.

Comment: Tested and approved Casimir et Hippolyte, answer updated, thanx for increasing my regex knowledge ;)